# 二つのファイルから文字列を読み込み、それを１ファイルの１行目、２ファイルの１行目、１ファイルの２行目、２ファイルの２行目と交互に新しいファイルに出力したい

Tags: c++

二つのファイルから文字列を読み込み、それを１ファイルの１行目、２ファイルの１行目、１ファイルの２行目、２ファイルの２行目と交互に新しいファイルに出力したいのですが、
自分の頭の中では文字列配列を３つ用意し、１つ目に１つ目のファイルから

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp1, * fp2, * fp3;
    fp1 = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("2.txt", "r");
    fp3 = fopen("4.txt", "w");

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int n=0, m=0;
    char s[20][20];
    char t[20][20];
    char st[20][20];

    while (fscanf(fp1, "%s", s[i][20]) != NULL) {
        st[2 * i][20] = s[i][20];
        i++;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp2, "%s", t[j][20]) != NULL) {
        st[2 * (1 + j)][20] = t[j][20];
        j++;
    }

    while (st[n][20] != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp3, "%s\n", st[n][20]);
        n++;
    }

    printf("出力しました");

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 困っているのは、どういうところですか？　それに対して、どんな対処をしたのですか？

Comment: 情報不足でした。まず、ファイルから文字列配列に文字列を格納する方法がわかりません。次に、２つの文字列を交互にファイル出力する方法がわかりません。

Comment: 二つのファイルと結果ファイル、それぞれ簡単なサンプルを交えての説明があると意図が伝わりやすいと思います。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、直接質問文に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

- 文字列は[`std::string`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- ファイル読み込みは[`std::ifstream`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)、書き出しは[`std::ofstream`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)
- １行読み込みは[`std::getline`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)
- 任意の書き込みは[`operator<<`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)、行末記号は[`std::endl`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)
- ストリームオブジェクトは[`bool`評価](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)を行うとエラーが発生していないか判定できる、つまり、まだ読み出し可能か判定できる
- ストリームオブジェクトは使い終えると自動的に閉じられる

辺りを組み込むと

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream f1{ "1.txt" }, f2{ "2.txt" };
    std::ofstream f3{ "4.txt" };
    for (std::string line; f1 || f2;) {
        if (f1 && getline(f1, line))
            f3 << line << std::endl;
        if (f2 && getline(f2, line))
            f3 << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

ぐらいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

もしC++ではなくCの範囲で行いたいのなら次のようになると思います。

`fgets`でバッファ (`buf`)に一行読み込み、成功した場合はその文字列を返します。ファイル終端などで読み取れなかった場合は`NULL`を返します。改行文字もバッファに格納されます。
http://www.c-tipsref.com/reference/stdio/fgets.html

`fputs`で文字列を書き込みます。
http://www.c-tipsref.com/reference/stdio/fputs.html

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;

    const int BUF_SIZE = 20;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    char *sz1, *sz2;

    fp1 = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("2.txt", "r");
    fp3 = fopen("4.txt", "w");


    while (true)
    {
        sz1 = fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, fp1);
        if (sz1 != NULL) {
            fputs(sz1, fp3);
        }
        sz2 = fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, fp2);
        if (sz2 != NULL) {
            fputs(sz2, fp3);
        }
        if (sz1 == NULL && sz2 == NULL) {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);

    return 0;
}
```

なおこのコードはエラー処理を行っていません。
また、19バイト以上の行があると意図しない結果になります。

C++をフルに使えるのならば sayuri さんの回答を参考にしてください。一行の長さに制限はありませんし、エラー時も安心です。